# UIScrollview scrollViewShouldScrollToTop - Slow down the scroll speed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

When the status bar is touched, by default,  a UIScrollview would scroll to the top. Does anyone know how I can control the speed of that automatic scroll up. I'd like to slow down the scroll to something a little more smooth and gradual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting decelerationRate property on your UISCrollView.